# Structural advise in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following applications:

- MVC - **Admincenter** - Where the owner of the whole project does his thing
- MVC - **Admincenter2** - Where the licensed software owner can control his thing
- WebAPI - **AppAPI** - Where app can get everything it needs

Now I was thinking all of the above could share some of the BO objects so I added another BO project all of them inherit. I also added another BLL project all of them inherit for common things like encryption etc.

Now the tricky part begins, I added Entity Framework. We are going to run code-first. I am unsure on how to position the whole thing properly.

Should I add an application just to build the database according to the mappings and then provide different context the the 3 applications above?

Any advise on the whole project or on how to work with EF in this scenario properly?

Comment: I assume only WebAPI will talk to database, and all other projects get data through it? You can even build a class project which has all the entities related to database, and then read/build database from there.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar set up and that is basically how it is structured (I assume you are using Visual Studio).

We have a web app project that contains both MVC and Web API controllers.  The MVC controllers essentially "bootstrap" the web app so, once it is loaded in the browser, all communication then takes place using Ajax calls to the Web API controllers.

We also have a separate class project (DLL) that contains the database context, entity classes and most of the business logic.  The Visual Studio "solution" then contains both the web app and the class library projects.

There are some simple things the MVC controllers do that don't apply to anything else so those methods didn't go into the class library.  But for the most part all database communication goes through the class library.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should separate data entities objects with DTOs (data transfer objects) that are used to transfer data between Web API and those two web applications. I would add class library project DAL(data access layer) with Entity framework, which is used for database operations and then with DTOs in BLL you'll get different application context

Comment: Can you provide an example of what a DTO would look like?

Comment: Here is the explanation for DTO pattern: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1050468/Data-Transfer-Object-Design-Pattern-in-Csharp